# converting class with aspect into single source

Tags: java, aspectj

Is there some tool for appying aspect to some class and generating final source into existing java source?
I want my initial class

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }

}
```

would be final source

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    System.out.println("Hello from AspectJ");
  }

}
```

after applying this tool with next aspect

```
public aspect HelloFromAspectJ {
  pointcut mainMethod() : execution(public static void main(String[]));
  after() returning : mainMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello from AspectJ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Andrew's answer is correct. You should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  AspectJ is not a tool for source code generation.  There are other tools around that might be better suited to your purpose, but unfortunately, I don't know enough about any of them to recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ acts on compiled code, not on source. If you don't really care about comments, variable names, formatting, etc. what you can do is apply aspectj on your compiled code and then decompile your code to generate the source code with aspects weaved in. It's not perfect but might be enough for your problem.